# PhpStorm git pull request default branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So when making a pull request, I need to select the branch I wish to pull onto. Is there any way I can select a default branch, that I wish to pull onto, instead of having to select the branch on every request?

We have a `main/master` branch and then a `development` branch. The request should go onto `development`, but the pre-selected branch is `main/master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ and other IntelliJ-based IDEs get info about a default branch from GitHub.

Please set the desired branch as "Default" in the GitHub Web interface and then, after refresh in IDE, you will get desired branch as default one.